# What is the point normal form for a point perpendicular to a line?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the point-normal from for the R2 line? Through P(–2, 1) and perpendicular to the line 5x – 3y = 8.

I keep messing it up and I can't figure out how to answer the question :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have the equation for a line, you get the equation for a perpendicular line by swapping the coefficients for $x$ and $y$, and changing the sign of one of them. So any line perpendicular to yours will have an equation of the form
$$
3x+5y=c
$$
for some real number $c$. Now just find the $c$ which makes this new line go through $P$.